# How to copy Int value between VCs without touching any buttons/views by user?

Tags: ios, swift

Is there any way to copy Int value of variable (btw, it is subclass number) with or without segue and not touching any buttons? The challenge is that my button is already performing other functions when pushed, besides return to previous view is done by code (meeting certain conditions) not user interaction. 
Appreciate you ideas.

The below method returns to previous view upon coded condition, but i cannot transfer values with it (sub class number).

```
let startView =
self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("startView")
as LSViewController    
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(startView, animated:
true)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a Int var (let's call it `var theInt = 0`) in your LSViewController and do:

```
let startView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("startView") as LSViewController
startview.theInt = theInt //the int you want to pass    
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(startView, animated: true)
```

Also note that your code does not return the previous view, it pushes a new view controller on the navigation controller stack.

Comment: Thanks. Great - it worked. Was writing around something similar nearby, but you gave the right syntax, which works in my project now.